# Is a non-principal ultrafilter the same thing as a free ultrafilter?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition, filters

Can someone please confirm if a non-principal ultrafilter is the same thing as a free ultrafilter. I keep finding conflicting definitions so am not sure.

Answer (score 5):

They're the same. Sometimes "free" is simply defined to mean "nonprincipal". Another definition given is:

> An ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ is *free* if $\bigcap \mathcal{F} = \emptyset$.

But that definition is equivalent to "nonprincipal":

- Clearly, a free ultrafilter is nonprincipal (even more clearly, a principal ultrafilter is not free).
- If an ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ on a set $X$ is nonprincipal, it contains $C_x \colon = X \setminus \{x\}$ for every $x \in X$, so its intersection is contained in the intersection of all of $C_x, x \in X$, which is $\emptyset$.

(If there's yet another definition of "free", I've never encountered it.)

Comment: Thanks BrianO that has cleared it up. I thought they were equivalent but wanted to make sure.

Comment: @hazza777 I kinda wish the term 'free ultrafilter' didn't exist :) Maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't seem to serve a good purpose. / Feel free to vote any of these answers correct ;/

Comment: @Brian: *Free* contrasts with *fixed*.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Ah. Wouldn't ya know it. We might say the same thing about "fixed" :) No doubt these various terms evolved in different areas of math. Thanks.